# What does DIN 5008 exactly say about percent character?

Tags: typography

On [Wikipedia: Percent sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign), there is following claim:

> In German, the space is prescribed by the regulatory body in the national standard [DIN 5008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_5008).

I can't speak German, so I can't read the whole standard. What does it say about it? Should there be a space or not?

And is what the standard says the same what is actually taught in German grammar?

Comment: Are you sure you need actually DIN 5008? Or rather tradition and good practice in professional typesetting? Since DIN 5008 is meant predominantly for office and bureaucratic use (business communication and administrative bodies), and it relates to writing on a typewriter (once) or standard office software (today), but not professional typesetting (e.g. publishing books).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a question about typography in German texts.
Typically, typography is not a subject in grammar teaching.
That results in a lot of awful typography all around.

As witnessed at [Prozentzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prozentzeichen):

> Wie bei Maßeinheiten wird zwischen die Zahl und das Prozentzeichen ein [geschütztes Leerzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesch%C3%BCtztes_Leerzeichen) gesetzt. Der Duden empfiehlt hier, einen kleineren, festen Zwischenraum zu verwenden. Nach dem Chicago Manual of Style soll allerdings in englischsprachigen Texten kein Zwischenraum zwischen eine Zahl und ein Prozentzeichen gesetzt werden.

Meaning: contrary to English rules (CMS), where a number should be followed without a space, in German texts the number is followed with a  [nonbreaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). (And Duden for example even recommends a narrower [spatium](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatium) [[Schmales Leerzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmales_Leerzeichen), [thin space]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space). That is extremely rare to find except in texts by people who really care about typography.) – Exact rules for English texts should follow the style guide that fits your application.

Non-breaking space means that between number and sign will never be a line break. Even that is quite rare in actual use, but very recommended. While most aspects of these special format spaces rules are nearly invisible to an untrained eye, a new line starting with a percent sign is.

A non-breaking space can be encoded in HTML with `&nbsp;` and is accessed for most editors on different platforms as follows:

```
Windows:    Alt+0+1+6+0 (doesn't always work)
Mac:        ⌥Opt+Space
Linux(X11): Compose, Space, Space or AltGr+Space
```

A spatium encoded in HTL with `&thinsp;` and is accessed

```
Windows:     Alt+2+0+0+6 (there are five versions between alt+2001 and alt+2007)
Mac:         Shift+Opt+Space
Linux:       Ctrl+Shift+Space
```

To illustrate:

- 100% version without space
- 100 % version with thin space
- 100 % version with normal non-breaking space for comparison

Comment: In Windows, a small space is <kbd>alt</kbd>+2006 (there are five versions between alt+2001 and alt+2007, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: Alll professional typesetting tools (such as InDesign, and all the others) provide special small spaces, specifically made for the respective font face. Traditionally they come as hair space, sixth space, thin space, quarter space and so on, sometimes also as n-space and m-space.

Comment: Note that according to ISO 80000 as well as _The International System of Units (SI),_ a space separates the number and the symbol % in English texts, too. (The Chicago Manual of Style is probably not a good source for technical and scientific writing.)

Comment: @LangLangC How did you enter the thin space for illustration in the question editor? For me it is rendered way too big here.

Comment: @Thomas I did not. Held the SE editor for a limited beast and left if out myself. Thought visibility was bad just on my platform, since 2 ppl approved the edit. – But is this better now? To my eyes the difference is way to small. Maybe it's just the fonts?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis What did you change? I do not see the difference in the edit history.

Comment: In the raw edit content, I saw a `&thinsp;` **followed by a normal space**. That didn't look right (too wide). So I removed the normal space but left the `&thinsp;`, but apparently the SE Markdown interpreter turned that into a normal space and the `&thinsp;` disappeared. Not what I wanted, but there doesn't seem to be a proper way to avoid that, or I did something wrong. I guess the difference can't be seen.

Comment: Hmmm.. now I see the `&thinsp;` where it should be, and no normal space anymore. Weird! See here: https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/41552/revisions You can see I removed a space (marked with pink background and a strike mark).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's so. I failed to edit it the way I wanted in fixed-width editor, then the edit introduced sth I thought was invisible to me, only. Now when I copy the whole line of markdown side-by-side to an external editor an invisible character appeared (no real space, as you apparently saw). Sth is not right there. What you describe is invisible to me in the above post, in all available views in the SE editor. Your platform?

Comment: @LangLangC: currently: Windows 10, Firefox. The Mac is in repair.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the excellent answer by @LangLangC here the relevant passage from `DIN 5008:2011-04 Schreib- und Gestaltungsregeln für die Textverarbeitung` as requested in OP:

> 8.7  Prozent- und Promillezeichen
>
> Vor dem Prozent- und Promillezeichen wird ein Leerzeichen gesetzt. Das Leerzeichen entfällt bei Ableitungen.
>   **2 % Skonto**
>   **3 1/4 % Zinsen**
>   **38%ig**
>
> o/oo (mit Kleinbuchstaben o) oder  ‰
>   **2 o/oo**
>   **2 ‰ Maklergebühr**

Which translates roughly to:

> A space is to be placed in front of percent or permill signs. But not if used in derivative forms such as **38%ig**

(The second paragraph is about how to use o/oo as an replacement for the permill sign ‰)

Comment: Where did you get this? I searched for it, and found it to be extremely hard to get. I ended up ordering a book meant for students etc. - The official commission seems to offer a printed version of that document for, unbelievably, 130 euros. I thought something like this should be available online?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Welcome to DIN and its publishing company Beuth Verlag, I once thought as well DIN is public/common sense but it isn't.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I'm a student, so I have access via the online library of my institution.

Comment: @PeterE  Oh, public libraries, of course. Stupid that I did not think of them. - Well, so, but as long as this is not even publicly available (without hassle) - why should one care to follow it? Grmpf...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Well, no, not a *public* library. It's more like this: My institution has some kind of contract with the Beuth Verlag, which allows - for computers within the university network - access to some kind of (horrid) management software for DIN and other norms (called perinorm and apparently provided or soled by Beuth) which is apparently hosted by some institution of the state of Baden-Württemberg, which by the way is not the state my institution is in.